# Como evitar “congelamiento” mientras se ejecuta el programa

Tags: python, hilos

Estoy realizando un pequeño desarrollo con Python, el cual realiza una extracción de datos de tablas en SQL Server, coloque una barra de progreso para monitorear el avance pero debido a que se extraen gran cantidad de valores de las tablas el proceso se "congela" y no se aprecia el progreso de la barra, lo que necesito saber es si hay alguna forma de evitar que se congele y se pueda ver el avance de la barra. He tratado de usar Thread pero no he podido lograr que los 02 procesos se ejecuten en paralelo.

Coloco parte del código:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import urllib
import threading
from io import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

def consultaSQL(): 
    global conn
    global cursor
    global df
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                              "Server=ACN054PESQL01;"
                              "Database=dbpefem;"
                              "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        conn.commit()
        if categoria_req.get()=="" and modulo_req.get()=="" and periodo_ini.get()=="" and periodo_fin.get()=="":
            eDat.mensaje_salida("Error","Debe completar los campos requeridos")
            #messagebox.showwarning("Error","Debe completar los campos requeridos")
            ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=False,False,False,False
        elif categoria_req.get()=="" and modulo_req.get()=="" and periodo_ini.get()!="" and periodo_fin.get()!="":
            eDat.mensaje_salida("Error","Debe seleccionar una Categoria y/o Modulo")
            ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=False,False,True,True
        elif periodo_ini.get()=="" and periodo_fin.get()=="":
            eDat.mensaje_salida("Error","Debe completar un periodo de inicio y de fin")         
            ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=False,False,False,False
        elif periodo_ini.get()!="" and periodo_fin.get()=="":
            eDat.mensaje_salida("Aviso","Debe seleccionar un periodo de fin")   
            ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=False,False,True,False
        elif periodo_ini.get()=="" and periodo_fin.get()!="":
            eDat.mensaje_salida("Aviso","Debe seleccionar un periodo de inicio")    
            ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=False,False,False,True
        elif (periodo_ini.get()!="" or periodo_fin.get()!="") and int(periodo_ini.get())>int(periodo_fin.get()):
            eDat.mensaje_salida("Error","El Periodo Final debe ser Mayor al Periodo Inicial")   
            ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=False,False,True,True
        elif categoria_req.get()!="" and modulo_req.get()=="" and periodo_ini.get()!="" and periodo_fin.get()!="":
            if len(categoria_req.get())<4 and int(categoria_req.get())!=0:
                progressbar.start()
                respuesta=messagebox.askokcancel("Aviso","Se extraera los datos de la CP: "+ categoria_req.get()+ " con sus modulos si los hay")
                if respuesta==True:
                    ctrlcat,ctrlmod,ctrlin,ctrlfin=True,False,True,True
                    # EN ESTE PUNTO LA BARRA DE PROGRESO DEBERIA INICIAR Y EN PARALELO REALIZAR LA CONSULTA SQL
                    datos="SELECT * FROM HistoricRLDB WHERE [RegCentID] <>99 AND [ItemGroup] ="+str(categoria_req.get())+""+"AND [Period] BETWEEN " +str(periodo_ini.get())+"" +" AND " +str(periodo_fin.get())+"" 
                    df=pd.read_sql(datos,conn)
                    conn.commit()
                    # EN ESTE PUNTO LA BARRA DE PROGRESO DEBERIA FINALIZAR
                    eDat.fin_exito()
                    cursor.close()
                    conn.close()
                else:
                    categoria_req.set(0)
                    progressbar.stop()
            else:
                eDat.mensaje_salida("Error","Validar Codigo de la Categoria")
```

Comment: No veo claro cuáles son esos dos procesos que quieres ejecutar en paralelo. Como ya te dije en una pregunta (borrada) anterior, deberías mirar cómo acceder a la base de datos por páginas. En la documentación de [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) hay un parámetro para extraer datos como un iterador. Siento no serte de más ayuda.

Comment: Los 02 procesos que quiero que se ejecuten en paralelo son la Query a la base de datos y la barra de progreso, en la linea anterior a la consulta "datos=...." voy a hace un llamado para que se ejecute la barra de progreso, y justo hay es donde tengo el inconveniente, mientras la consulta se esta ejecutando la barra de progreso se queda detenida y eso es lo que quiero evitar